# Understanding javascript callback with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, callback, dom-events

I have an object literal returned by a function, and in turn this object creates an iframe and does a few things when the DOM is loaded within that iframe. I want to be able to "get" the value returned by the callback when the event is triggered. Here is a simplified object:

```
var myFunc = function (url) {
  return {
      url: url,
      myMethod: function () {

          // some code here to create my iframe.

          var callbackFunc = function (event) {
             // do some stuff with the dom.
             return aValueAsynchronously;
          };

          var async = my_iframe.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callbackFunc, true);
          my_iframe.src = this.url;
      }      
  }
}
```

After reading this code I'm using it as follow outside of it:

```
var myValue = myFunc.myMethod('http://www.example.org');
```

and when example.org is done loading in the iFrame, the `DOMContentLoaded` callback is triggered, and the value (after some logic) is returned. How do I get this value to be assigned to `myValue` (the line above)? I understand I need to use a callback to do that, but where and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the code you have shown cannot be called by `myFunc.myMethod`, as the function value does not have a `myMethod` property. Instead, the function *returns* an object with that property. So to start with you need to:

```
var myValue = myFunc('http://foo.com').myMethod();
```

However, that is only going to invoke the method that sets up the callback. To actually have access to the `aValueAsynchronously` you could create a closure around that value:

```
var myFunc = function(url){
  var aValueAsynchronously;
  return {
    val : aValueAsynchronously,
    myMethod: function(){
      var callback = function(evt){
        aValueAsynchronously = ...;
      };
      ...register your callback...
    }
  };
};

var obj = myFunc('http://foo.com');
obj.myMethod();
...some time passes, and eventually the callback occurs...
console.log( obj.val ); // This will be what was set in your callback
```

Instead of that, though, I would personally write the code so that I could pass in my own callback to execute from the iframe callback, and just pass the special value to my callback directly. (That sounds confusing; see code below.) That way you don't have to wait until the value becomes available, but rather you get notified when it is:

```
var myFunc = function(url,whenDone){
  return {
    myMethod: function(){
      var callback = function(evt){
        var aValueAsynchronously = ...;
        whenDone(aValueAsynchronously);
      };
      ...register your callback...
    }
  };
};

var myObj = myFunc('http://foo.com',function(specialValue){
  // use specialValue here
});
myObj.myMethod(); // Go
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll try the two solutions you have described and see how this works! :-)

Comment: Love the second solution with passing the callback value directly! It truly demonstrates the strength of JS! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If *myValue* is in scope for *callBack*, just assign to it. If it isn't in scope, then it must be accessed as a property of some object and a reference to that object must be in scope for *callBack*.

In the simple case, if *myValue* is global and you are expecting the code to run in a browser, then *callBack* can set `window.myValue = ...;`. Otherwise, *callBack* needs to access it as a property of the global object (which is equivalent to *window* in a browser).

So in your function you might have:

```
      var callbackFunc = function (event) {
         // do some stuff with the dom.

         window.myValue = aValueAsynchronously;

         return aValueAsynchronously;
      };
```

Or have I completely missed the point?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not running this in the browser! Phrogz solution worked.

Comment: Then you can get a reference to the global object and use that instead. But yes, I think Phrogz got it.